# What day is displayed on the U.S. Customs and Border Protection's travel history for each arrival?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, history

What day is displayed on the U.S. Customs and Border Protection's [travel history](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search) for each arrival? Is it when the flight actually landed, the flight was scheduled to land,  when passing the immigration, etc.?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the date on which the CBP officer (or automated system) decided to admit you.  It should be the same date as that stamped in your passport.

Comment: Often, it is the date on which a machine such as a global entry kiosk decided to admit us.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan fair enough.  Edited.  But in my experience as a programmer I wouldn't be surprised if the kiosks actually use the date on which the session was begun, or the date of the aircraft's arrival, or some other source for the date, even if legally they shouldn't.  Come to think of it, an officer's systems might do the same. 
 Having never arrived before midnight but cleared passport control after midnight (much less begun clearing passport control before midnight but finished after), I begin to suspect that this answer could in fact be incorrect.

Comment: Hmmm. If a CBP officer is using an inked stamp, there has to be some point at which the officer changes the date on the stamp. Do they do it mid-shift, or does the stamp reflect when the officer came on duty and set up their work area? The big picture is to do everything you can to avoid depending on the exact date. Plan to arrive when your visa is definitely valid. Leave at least a couple of days before you are required to do so.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan indeed.  I suspect that they do it at midnight.  But I don't generally arrive just before midnight, so I've never witnessed it.  And if they are legally supposed to use the flight's landing time as the date of admission (which I doubt) then they would have trouble processing (e.g) two planes that landed at the same terminal, one just before and one just after midnight, so the passengers from the two flights are mixed.

Comment: 20 years ago I would have agreed about the kiosk using some simplified date rule, but having a computer know the current date and time to within seconds is so easy now that there is no reason to avoid it.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan it's not about what's easy or simple.  It has been easy for computers to know the current date and time for well more than 20 years.  It's about programmers inadvertently introducing logic errors leading to the use of the wrong variable to identify the relevant time.