# What day is displayed on the U.S. Customs and Border Protection's travel history for each departure?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, international-travel, history

What day is displayed on the U.S. Customs and Border Protection's [travel history](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search) for each departure and arrival? Is it when the flight actually took off, the flight was scheduled to take off, or when passing the security, etc.?

[image]

Comment: It's certainly not when you pass security, because they don't record that, and because it's possible to pass security and then not board the plane.

Comment: I am *sure* you've already asked this question. The related one for "arrival" [still exists](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159078/what-day-is-displayed-on-the-u-s-customs-and-border-protections-travel-history). Please do not delete and re-post questions just because you didn't get the answer you wanted.

Comment: @GregHewgill please don't make false allegations

Comment: Are you denying that you asked this exact same question prevously?

Comment: @GregHewgill I'm denying I deleted it.

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose questions also get deleted automatically for attracting downvotes and no answers. That's an even worse reason to re-post the question, as it looks like it's just going to get voted down again. For those with enough rep to see it, here's the previous community-deleted question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159077/what-day-is-displayed-on-the-u-s-customs-and-border-protections-travel-history

Comment: @GregHewgill I don't care about downvotes and the question is still valid

Comment: For those with not enough rep to see it, the previous community-deleted question was removed because of only 1 downvote

Comment: It could possibly be when they're made aware of your departure.  According to my travel history I have 88 more arrivals into the USA than departures :)  Additionally my most recent arrival from my travel history doesn't match my I-94 most recent date of entry.  I'm not sure I'd rely on this information for anything other than being information :)

Comment: I assume there is no single answers (different possibilities, on different time, places, etc.). And I think it doesn't matter much, but if you are near the limit dates, keeps the documentation: e.g. late flight, but also all reasonable cause that caused you to depart few day later [cancelled flights, police detection, health, etc.]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While we don't know yet the exact answer, the following comment from [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog) drastically reduce the time window:

> It's certainly not when you pass security, because they don't record that, and because it's possible to pass security and then not board the plane. – [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog) [Oct 6 at 14:12](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159718/what-day-is-displayed-on-the-u-s-customs-and-border-protections-travel-history#comment401018_159718)

This means the day is displayed on the U.S. Customs and Border Protection's travel history for each departure is either when the flight actually took off, or when the flight was scheduled to take off or close to that time (e.g., entering plane).

Comment: This is not really an answer. A guess posted as a comment because there is no knowledge (yet) and in my view not worth accepting at all. (I am not going to delete as not an answer as improvements can make it in something acceptable.)

Comment: @Willeke It's definitely not written as a guess ("It's certainly not when you pass security, because they don't record that"). How do you suggest to improve?

Comment: Wait till someone (maybe yourself) actually knows the answer. (Yes, waiting for that answer would mean that this question gets closed but that is the way of the site.)

Comment: @Willeke I don't understand if your issue is that phoog does indicate the precise time or that you think that phoog is making a guess.